# Is it possible to connect Samsung Galaxy Ace with USB but without Kies?

Tags: usb, samsung-kies, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace and my problem is that I am unable to connect the USB to my PC, without starting Kies software. Is it possible that I can connect my Ace to my Laptop without using Kies, because if I have to connect my mobile to any other PC, that may not contain the Kies?

Comment: Why do you want to connect it to a pc, moving files/images/music or syncing contacts/calendar or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Disable USB Debugging mode in `Settings -> Development`, and try to connect the device. I'm assuming you have installed Samsung Kies, because all device drivers for Samsung devices are present only in that software, and not on the device.

Comment: thanks dude, it all working just by disabling USB debugging, and without KIES... thanks a lot, there is no need for KIES, if you disable USB Debugging

Comment: @Abbas: If you can accept this answer by clicking on the right mark which appears below, me and others would be thankful to you (others because they won't have to look at this question, since it is already answered) :)